# Get the host and port from outside of the controller in Asp Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-2.0

In an ASP Net Core 2.0 application, how can I get the hostname and port from  outside of the controller?

Comment: Extract it from the request which you can get from the HttpContext, which can be accessed via `IHttpContextAccessor` outside of the controller. make sure to register it with DI container in composition root so it can be injected.

Comment: Just to expand on @Nkosi's comment, you need access to the HttpContext,  just as you'd do in a controller. Therefore, that context must be injected into whatever non-controller class is needing this. However, it's generally far better to simply pass in the information you need than the entire context. In other words, if you have a class that needs the hostname and port, then instantiate that in your controller with the hostname and port. Leave HttpContext to the controller.